# Argument of type '{ websocket: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter when using fastify/websocket

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, websocket, fastify

I have a new project using fastify and Typscript and I am getting the following issue:

```
Argument of type '{ websocket: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RouteShorthandOptions
...ts(2345)
```

Here is the code for reference:

```
import path from "path";
import Fastify, { FastifyInstance, RouteShorthandOptions } from 'fastify'

const fastify: FastifyInstance = Fastify({});
fastify.register(require('@fastify/websocket'));
fastify.register(require('@fastify/static'), {
    root: path.join(__dirname, '../../client/dist')
});

fastify.get('connection', { websocket: true }, (connection, req) => {
    connection.socket.on('message', message => {
        ...do stuff
    });
});
```

I have already seen someone had opened an issue (https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/2967) that wound up being a peer module issue.  But I don't really have much in the project yet...
`package.json`

```
...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.7.1",
    "@types/ws": "^8.5.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fastify/static": "^6.5.0",
    "@fastify/websocket": "^7.0.0",
    "fastify": "^4.4.0"
  }
...
```

I also know from the Git issue they have it still defined in the source: https://github.com/fastify/fastify-websocket/blob/master/index.d.ts#L16

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2016",
    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs",
    /* Emit */
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    /* Interop Constraints */
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [ "src/**/*" ]
}
```

Why am I still seeing this TS error and how should I resolve it? Or do I have to get it to ignore somehow by making TS less strict?

Comment: I am facing the same error.. did you get any solution to the problem?

Comment: @JameerKhan Unfortunately, no.  I just cannot find enough documentation around these components of Fastify working together.  I wound up just using `path` and `WebSocket` with `Express` since I already know how to do that.

Comment: Probably I was able to fix it.. I just needed to import the `@fastify/websocket` package and then register in fastify instead of just requiring (`require`) it the old way.. then it worked..

Comment: @JameerKhan, it does seem like that works.  If you post an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

For me this started happening because I had switched from `npm` to `yarn` with its pnp (Plugin'n'Play) module resolution scheme. I don't really understand why that would cause this problem, but here is what I did to fix it:

```bash
# Switch from pnp to node-modules
yarn config set nodeLinker node-modules

# Actually install
yarn install

# This will force Typescript to rebuild everything
find -name "*.tsbuildinfo" -exec rm {} \;

# Do the actual build
yarn run build
```

Note: I'm not sure if there is a better way to force tsc to recompile other than removing the `tsbuildinfo` files. I noticed the command I mentioned above will also delete matching files in `node_modules`, but this should be harmless.